# Download app from eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, download

I am new to this so I'm not sure its possible. I am trying to find some literature about downloading an app to my device that I have created straight from my eclipse. Just for testing purposes. Does anyone have some links or instructions? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You mean download the app to you device for testing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're asking how to install the app you made in Eclipse directly onto your device, is that correct?

If so...

1. Make sure you have your correct drivers for your device installed on the computer
2. Go to Settings > Apps > Development and check on USB Debugging. This may also be found under Settings > Developer Options
3. Plug your device into the computer and it should automatically connect to your Eclipse adt plugin

If you don't want to install the drivers you can alternatively...

Go to the folder where your app project is located and open up the folder named bin. In there you should find [YourAppName].apk in there. You can then e-mail this to yourself, or transfer it onto the device's SD Card. From there you need to use a file management app to open the file and install it.

The first option may take longer at first, but makes developing much easier and faster in the long run. The second option is just the most basic manner of accomplishing it.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was asking Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to answer it for you. It is a very useful thing to have set up in order to develop!